# tgz file extracted folders has no files

Tags: archive, unzip

When I tried extracting  a tgz file using archive manager, the extracted folders has no files. I tried other softwares like 7zip also. But that also is not returning the same error. Can you suggest a workaround. TIA

Comment: Have you confirmed the source `.tgz` file is valid? An incomplete archive may not expand correctly.

Comment: Yes. I confirmed it. Infact it is opening in Windows